# Why does my app crash after launching photo intent, but before onActivityResult() is called?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-image, android-camera-intent

I am using the following code to request an image from the user:

```
        Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
        pickIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
        pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        pickIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        // child intents to allow capture image and video
        Intent capturePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Intent captureVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        // set max capture size
        capturePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 20971520L); //20*1024*1024=20MB
        captureVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 20971520L); //20*1024*1024=20MB

        // present import chooser
        String chooserTitle = "Import Media From...";
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, chooserTitle);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{capturePhotoIntent, captureVideoIntent});
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, MEDIA_CAPTURE);
```

This works on my Nexus 5, but crashes on my Galaxy S5. The crash occurs after I have taken the photo, and tap "Save," but before `onActivityResult()` is called. I have also tried supplying a URI via `capturePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri)`, but the same behavior occurs.

I get no stack trace for my code, since nothing is passed back to my activity; the activity just crashes.

I've been working on this for days. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Look into LogCat. You would find the information there.

Comment: @StenSoft I have looked at the logs for my app, as well as the entire system logcat output. It doesn't show anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. My app was running out of memory. I solved this by adding `android:largeHeap="true"` to my AndroidManifest.xml, as well as redesigning the code that managed the picture data.